# Checkstyle indentation without specifying "size"

Tags: checkstyle

I'm using Checkstyle to do some audits on code submitted by students in a university programming class. I want to confirm that the code has consistent indentation, but I don't want to impose the specific amount of indentation on them (i.e. I don't care if they use 2 spaces or 4, as long as they're consistent).

It's easy enough to check indentation with this configuration:

```
<module name="Checker">
<property name="severity" value="warning" />
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="Indentation">
      <property name="basicOffset" value="4" />
      <property name="braceAdjustment" value="0" />
    </module>
  </module>
</module>
```

But that will only accept code that uses 4 spaces. Is it possible to have it accept any consistent number of spaces, or barring that, accept either 2, 3, or 4 spaces as a valid style?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at custom [CascadeIndentationCheck](https://github.com/teamed/qulice/blob/master/qulice-checkstyle/src/main/java/com/qulice/checkstyle/CascadeIndentationCheck.java). It has hardcoded amount of spaces to 4, but as the check is fairly short and understandable, it should be easy to adopt it to allow also 2 or 3 spaces.

Comment: Looking at the suggested code, it's not at all clear how to modify it to detect consistent indentation which is what the question asked for.  Changing it to allow for any mix of say 2 or 3 would be easy, but it isn't obvious how to change that to check for the same amount every time.  This code also doesn't seem like it pays attention to what should be indented, but instead just checks that each line is either the same as the previous or indented by N.